# Java gradle execute code

Tags: java, gradle, build

I follow this [starter tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/gradle/).

I can not run the code with this command :

```
$ java -cp gs-gradle-0.1.0.jar hello.HelloWorld
```

I have this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/time/LocalTime
    at hello.HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.joda.time.LocalTime
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
```

All import classes are not found. But with gradle command it works :

```
$ ./gradlew run
```

Why with java command, it doesn't work ?

Thanks

Comment: It appears the issue is that JodaTime isn't on your runtime classpath.

Comment: The point of the application plugin is to generate a zip or tar file containing everything you need to run the app, including startup scripts that set up the right classpath and run the application. You should use them.

Comment: So i must download all jar files that I import in my class ? And put them in /libs ?

Comment: No. You need to use the startup scripts generated by the build. Please read https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it does not work, the Tutorial also told you so.

The `application` plugin adds the `run` task (and other tasks) that put your dependency on the classpath.

If you use the `distZip` or `distTar` task you get an archive with all your dependencies and with start scripts that set the correct classpath that you can use to run your application.

Read more about the `application` plugin at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html.